# OpenCV R6010() abort has been called error in visual studio 2012

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am a beginner about OpenCV. I searched and tried to execute some basic OpenCV codes. When I tried running one of them, I got "R6010 -abort() has been called" error. I also tried to debug codes but this time on line 28 it gave me "Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000A7F732F350." error.

```
// work5animage.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#include "opencv2\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;
int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
// Read images
Mat color= imread("resized_love.jpg");
Mat gray= imread("resized_love.jpg", 0);
// Write images
imwrite("lenaGray.jpg", gray);


// Get same pixel with opencv function
int myRow=color.cols-1;
int myCol=color.rows-1;
Vec3b pixel= color.at<Vec3b>(myRow, myCol);   //This is where I get the err.
cout << "Pixel value (B,G,R): (" << (int)pixel[0] << "," <<
(int)pixel[1] << "," << (int)pixel[2] << ")" << endl;
// show images
imshow("Lena BGR", color);
imshow("Lena Gray", gray);
// wait for any key press
waitKey(1000);
return 0;
}
```

I saw some relavant problems but I couldn't find a convenient answer for me. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose jpg doesn't store in the plain 2D format like you want to access it. Convert it to bmp, read that in and try again.